# How to update a yaml file with dynamic properties in Rust?

Tags: serialization, rust, yaml

Consider a yaml file with the current content:

```
namespaces:
  production:

helmRepos:
  stable: "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"

context: monitoring

apps:
  datadog:
    enabled: true
    namespace: production
    chart: stable/datadog
    version: "1.38.7"
    valuesFile: "values.yaml"
```

I would like to programatically update the value of the property `version` in this file. 
**What would be the best way to do that?**

What makes it a bit more difficult is that I don't think I can use a struct to deserialize/serialize this file, because for example the keys under `helmRepos` can be anything.

I have looked at the [serde_yaml](https://crates.io/crates/serde_yaml) crate, but I couldn't figure out how to change a value in a file that has unpredictable keys and then serialize it back. I am also quite a beginner in Rust, so I might be missing something obvious because of that.

Comment: You can deserialize into a `serde_yaml::Value`, change the version, serialize back.

Comment: Hi @SvenMarnach! Do you happen to have an example on how to that? Specifically on `change the version, serialize back` part.

Comment: You can also use a `struct` with the unknown keys if you use [`#[serde(flatten)]`](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html#capture-additional-fields).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `serde` to modify your files, the basic approach is *deserialize, modify, reserialize*. This will remove all comments and custom formatting like empty lines from your yaml files, so I'm not sure this is the approach you want.

Using `serde_yaml`, there are different options to achieve this goal. The easiest in my opinion is to use the `Value` type, which can represent an arbitrary yaml value:

```
const DOC: &str = r#"namespaces:
  production:

helmRepos:
  stable: "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"

context: monitoring

apps:
  datadog:
    enabled: true
    namespace: production
    chart: stable/datadog
    version: "1.38.7"
    valuesFile: "values.yaml"
"#;

fn main() {
    let mut value: serde_yaml::Value = serde_yaml::from_str(DOC).unwrap();
    *value
        .get_mut("apps")
        .unwrap()
        .get_mut("datadog")
        .unwrap()
        .get_mut("version")
        .unwrap() = "1.38.8".into();
    serde_yaml::to_writer(std::io::stdout(), &value).unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9c65832af6fe517a4d847353163aae8)

You probably want proper error handling instead of using `unwrap()` everywhere. If you are fine with using `unwrap()` the above code can be simplified to

```
let mut value: serde_yaml::Value = serde_yaml::from_str(DOC).unwrap();
value["apps"]["datadog"]["version"] = "1.38.8".into();
serde_yaml::to_writer(std::io::stdout(), &value).unwrap();
```

If you don't want to lose comments and empty lines, things get a lot more tricky. The proper solution for that goal is to use the `yaml_rust` crate to parse your files and determine what line to change. However, you can probably get away with some ad-hoc approach for finding the right line if you don't need your code to be robust.

Comment: I think that you can write `value["apps"]["datadog"]["version"] = "1.38.8".into()`

Comment: I kept the version with explicit `unwrap()` to make it easier to add proper error handling.

Comment: Thank you @SvenMarnach for the detailed answer! And for the suggestion about `yaml_rust` and not loosing comments, I didn't think about that so far. I will look into using `yaml_rust` as well, otherwise I will most likely go with the `serde_yaml` solution.

Comment: Building a robust, correct implementation that only changes the version string without touching anything else is surprisingly complex. Yaml is actually a complex language, so you need a proper parser to make this work in all cases. However, it is possible to build something simple that is Good Enough by implementing some ad-hoc parsing yourself to find the line with the version, and then use a regular expression to replace it. It will be possible to fool that implementation by carefully crafted input, but it shouldn't be too difficult to get it right for all cases that matter to you.

Comment: @SvenMarnach regarding the last part of your answer:
`If you don't want to lose comments and empty lines, things get a lot more tricky. The proper solution for that goal is to use the yaml_rust crate to parse your files and determine what line to change. However, you can probably get away with some ad-hoc approach for finding the right line if you don't need your code to be robust.`

I understood from this bit that if want to keep comments then I should use `yaml_rust`. But parsing with yaml_rust doesn't seem to take comments either. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Example with `yaml_rust` here:  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11e6c8af28783b677dc4229d78220094

Comment: Reading your comment above suggests that the way to keep the file as is is to skip any yaml parser and just find the line in the file and change it through other means. But that's not what the last part of the answer suggests to me.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit vague there. Indeed I think that the best way to keep formatting and comments is to keep the file as is, and just find the string token you want to replace. However, finding that token in a way that is correct for all inputs is _hard_, and requires a full yaml parser. However, you wouldn't use that parser to parse the whole file to a yaml value, but rather to get a parse tree of the file. The parse tree generally contains information where each token can be found in the source file, so the parse tree allows you to find the string to change in a robust way.

Comment: I actually haven't used `yaml_rust` myself. I just had a quick look, and it doesn't actually expose the parse tree, but an event stream interface instead, which can be used for the same purpose. You need the [`MarkedEventReceiver`](https://docs.rs/yaml-rust/0.4.3/yaml_rust/parser/trait.MarkedEventReceiver.html), which will send you events together with their position in the source code.

Comment: However, I wouldn't really recommend this approach. Finding the correct lines for _all_ possible inputs is probably not needed, so some ad-hoc code to find the correct token will likely do the trick.

Comment: Here is perhaps a more demonstrative example of comments not being preserved using the `yaml_rust` approach: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7344edc0225df01c2173d914a9c6b615